# Angular 5 - "Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: angular

In Angular 5, for input

```html
<input name="techSpecMeta.make" [(ngModel)]="techSpecMeta.make" type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Enter car brand">
```

getting error
Cannot read property 'make' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private vahinfo: VehicleInfo) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  techSpecMeta: {};
  onSave = function(vehicle, isValid: boolean) {
    this.vahinfo.saveVehicle(vehicle).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.data)
    }, error => this.errorMessage = error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the techSpecMeta in you component ? You can do that as: techSpecMeta: {}; at the component level.

Comment: hi rohan, 
yes my component.ts

export class UserComponent implements OnInit{

 constructor(private vahinfo : VehicleInfo) { }
    ngOnInit(){

    }
      techSpecMeta: {};
         onSave = function(vehicle, isValid : boolean){
      this.vahinfo.saveVehicle(vehicle)
      .subscribe( data=> {
       console.log(data.data)
      },error => this.errorMessage = error)
     }
}

Comment: have you assigned techSpecMeta to the model that you have created?

Comment: This usually happens when the resources are async. To avoid the error, try to put the element holding the model inside a `*ngIf` tag. Like - `<div *ngIf='x.a'>{{x.a}}</div>`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
techSpecMeta: {};
```

In Type script this means to declare a property of type `{}` with no value initialized. It is the same as:

```
techSpecMeta: Object;
```

You should instead be doing

```
techSpecMeta = {};
```

To make the binding work, you will need the property `make` as well.

```
techSpecMeta = {make: null};
```

Ideally you would create a class/interface for TechSpecMeta

```
class TechSpecMeta {
    make: null;
    anotherProperty: null;
}
```

and use it in your component

```
techSpecMeta = new TechSpecMeta();
```

Comment: In a single form I want to post data for  
        vehRegNumber
        techSpecMeta.make
        techSpecMeta.model                
        
        servSpecMeta.buy.purchaseDate': 
        servSpecMeta.buy.purchasePrice':
Is my approach right with following class definition and importing?

vehicle.ts------------------------------------------
class TechSpecMeta{
    make: null;
    model: null;
}

class ServSpecMeta{
    buy: {
        purchaseDate: null;
        purchasePrice: null;
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please do not put code in comments. Add the code and query in your question and comment that you have updated your question.

Answer (score 8):

please try to intialize it as below description

public techSpecMeta =  `<any>` {};

Answer (score 2):

Please try to initialize it as below:

```
techSpecMeta = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting same issue in my component.html file where I have defined the ngModel property to client.firstName, while you are creating object in component.ts file make sure object should be client. for example 
**client** : Client =  {
    firstName:'',
    lastName:'',
    email:'',
    phone:'',
    balance:0
  }
Client is interface. small letter client is object which I mentioned in the component.html.

Comment: I was stuck at this error for an hour now.. reading comments finally helped. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your **techSpecMeta** object do not have **make** property. Try initializing one in Init method.

```
ngOnInit(){
this.techSpecMeta= {make: ""};  }
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize it in ngOnInit using as TechSpecMeta (assuming you created an interface.

it should look something like this :

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  techSpecMeta!: TechSpecMeta;

  constructor(private vahinfo: VehicleInfo) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  
  this.techSpecMeta = {} as TechSpecMeta;

  }

  onSave = function(vehicle, isValid: boolean) {
    this.vahinfo.saveVehicle(vehicle).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.data)
    }, error => this.errorMessage = error)
  }
}
```