# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'login'

Tags: angular, typescript, object, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying to setup a login page, and on my login.ts im declaring an object.

```
public User: {
    login:"",
    senha:"",
  };
```

Then im using [ngModel] to store the values inside these parameters inside my objects.

```
       <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Informe seu CNS ou CPF</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="User.login"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Senha</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="User.senha"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

For some unknown reason to me, i keep getting this error and my page won't load.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'login'

Comment: I guess you mean `User = {...}`

Comment: Yes, i have no idea how i didn't notice it, lol thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 - "Cannot read property of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577137/angular-5-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have to define your `User` properly. Something like this:

```
public User: any = {
  login: '',
  senha: ''
};
```