# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property in Angular bundle

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am new to angular development. After bundle my angular project, I try to run it with http-server but there is a error in browser console and I attached that error with this question. My project successfuly run with ng serve command. Is there any way to debug my bundle with my angular project?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577137/angular-5-cannot-read-property-of-undefined

Comment: @AbolfazlR this is happen after ng build and serve http-server from dist folder. in this case how to fined error in my ts files. This error not happen when i run my project using ng serve

Comment: try `ng serve --prod` see if it gives you the error then

Comment: @Stavm yes, it gives same error